# Passing value on form1 to form2 and Updating database

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-update

I passed a value on form1 to form2 and used that value on form2 for the "where" of the query. basically when the user click a datagrid column on form1 and press edit button. we will go to form2 with the value of the datagrid passed on to a textbox. I successfully pass the value to the textbox but failed to insert it. heres the code

// form1

```
       private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    { 

        var frm2 = new frmItem(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        frm2.Show();
        this.Hide();
        frm2.Text = "EDIT";

    }
```

// form 2

```
   public frmItem(string s)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    txtTry.Text = s;
}

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Text == "EDIT")
        {         
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format("Update Items Set (Barcode='" + txtcode.Text + "' ,Productname= '" + txtitemname.Text + "',Prices= '" + txtPrices.Text + "' ,Quantity= '" + txtquantity.Text + "' ,Brand= '" + txtbrand.Text + "',Expiry= '" + txtexpiry.Text + "',Description='" + txtdescription.Text + "' ,Critical= '" + txtcritical.Text + "' Barcode  = '" + txtTry.Text + "')", cn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Records Updated!");
            txtcode.Text = "";
            txtitemname.Text = "";
            txtPrices.Text = "";
            txtquantity.Text = "";
            txtbrand.Text = "";
            txtexpiry.Text = "";
            txtdescription.Text = "";
            txtcritical.Text = "";

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid");
        }            

    }
```

Comment: Start by using SQL Parameters.  Your code is forcing what looks like ought to be numbers (price, quantity and a date) to text.  Gluing SQL together like that also opens you to SQL injection attacks, data type mismatches and query format errors

Comment: See my two form porject at following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: There are a few things wrong 1) You have cn in the cmd.CommandText statement. 2)  You are using single quotes in the cmd.CommandText which is specifying string objects where prices and cost are numbers.  Try this : cmd.CommandText = string.Format("Update Items Set (Barcode='{0}' ,Productname= '{1}',Prices= {2} ,Quantity= {3} ,Brand= '{4}',Expiry= '{5}',Description='{6}' ,Critical= '{7}' Barcode  = '{8}')",
               txtcode.Text, txtitemname.Text, txtPrices.Text, txtquantity.Text, txtbrand.Text, txtexpiry.Text, txtdescription.Text, txtcritical.Text. txtTry.Text);